# Default value of the function parameter is "passing_parametr"*2

Tags: c++, function, scope

I wrote the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int x, int y=2*x)
{
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",foo(5));
}
```

But I've compile-time error `error: local variable ‘x’ may not appear in this context`
But I'm expected that it will be OK, because 3.3.4/1:

> In a function declaration, or in any function declarator except the
>   declarator of a function definition (8.4),names of parameters (if
>   supplied) have function prototype scope, which terminates at the end
>   of the nearest enclosing function declarator.

The end nearest enclosing function declarator is `}`, the point of declaration is immediately after `int x`. So why it doesn't work?

Comment: The only thing i could think of such working is `int foo(const int &x, int y=2*x)`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The same error is caused.

Comment: I was afraid so :-/ ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not because of scope. `8.3.6/7` says that

> Local variables shall not be used in a default argument.

and `8.3.6/9`:

> Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called. The order of evaluation of function
>   arguments is unspeciﬁed. **Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in a default argument,
>   even if they are not evaluated.** Parameters of a function declared before a default argument are in scope
>   and can hide namespace and class member names.

It makes sense to prohibit this, since the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. What would the value of `y` be if `2*x` would be evaluated before the argument of `x`?

Comment: Does default value can be any valid expression besides the parameter of function?

Comment: @St.Antario Yes, you can do all sorts of weird things: [Example.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75d058835ada69c1)

Comment: Nice example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does this snippet work for you?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int x, int y)
{
    return y;
}

int foo(int x)
{
    return foo(x, x*2);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",foo(5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are sending one arg to foo function when you have written it taking 2 param
this way it should work :

```
int foo(int x)
{
    int y=2*x;
    return y;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",foo(5));
}
```

Comment: You don't understand me. I was looked for formal language rules.

Comment: C++ supports default values for arguments. Just not the way the asker wants.