# C++ default argument value using the value of another parameter

Tags: c++

I am aware that the default argument value for a parameter can't be the value of another parameter. For example

```
void foo( int a, int b = a );
```

Obviously the default value of b is not a compile time constant but it seems to me that the compiler could generate code to do this.

I'm sure there is a good reason for not allowing this, I am wondering what it is?

Comment: Probably because it's confusing as hell

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725995/default-value-of-the-function-parameter-is-passing-parametr2/23726055#23726055

Comment: I am aware that the current standard does not allow this because of the unspecified evaluation of arguments, and also that you can achieve the same end via overloading. I assume that in the general case this would require the compiler to have some sort of DAG dependency tree for argument evaluations, in other words yes I agree that this imposes requirements concerning order of argument evaluation. So is this the main reason, that it makes life harder for the compiler or is it just that overloading allows you to do something similar so why add complexity to the language?

Answer (score 5):

It's because you've no guarantee about the order of evaluation of the parameters.

Iso standard section 8.3.6 specifies clearly why:

> The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.
>   Consequently, parameters of a function shall not be used in a default
>   argument, even if they are not evaluated. Parameters of a function
>   declared before a default argument are in scope and can hide 
>   namespace and class member names.

However if you could in some cases opt for a function overloading for getting the desired result:

```
void foo(int a, int b);
void foo(int a);

void foo(int a, int b) {
    cout << "foo with 2 arguments" << a << "," << b<<endl;
}

void foo(int a) {
    cout << "wrapper foo with 1 argument =>";
    foo(a, a);
}
```

Comment: This is true on the *caller* side. The OP's question is about the *callee* side. Edit: with citation, your point is much clearer. +1

Comment: @WhozCraig the standard also makes clear that default argument is for the caller side and not for the callee:  "Default arguments will be used in calls where trailing arguments are missing." The callee does not know when arguments are missing.  You could try to use overloading if you want it on the callee side.

Answer (score 4):

The standard does not mandate that `a` must be initialized before `b`. Hence, it is undefined behavior.

Comment: What does the initialization order have to do with all that? `a` is a parameter, and it is evaluated before the code of `foo()` starts executing.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight See 8.3.6/9. The default argument is evaluated whenever the `foo` in the example is called with a single argument. But because the order is unspecified, the compiler is not required to evaluate `a` before it evaluates `b`.

Comment: Since there is no guarantee that `a` is evaluated before `b`, the value of `b` can be garbage if it is evaluated before `a`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1880877/2591612

Comment: I see - so the answer is actually that they did it to preserve an ability to evaluate parameters in arbitrary order, which would have been lost by adding this feature.

Comment: @haccks Yep, it's true for C because C does not allow default arguments :P (I know you mean order of evaluation :))

Comment: @Praetorian; hahaha. I mean that the order of evaluation of arguments of function. `f(i, i++);`--> undefined result.